# Multiple instances of a UserControl with DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, xaml

I've created a `UserControl` which uses multiple `DependencyProperties`. When I have just one instance of the `UserControl`, everything works as expected. However, if I create multiple instances of the object, only the first instance works(note: no errors are thrown). The only thing I can think of is that having multiple instances of a `DependencyProperty` is not possible. Is this correct? If so, are there any alternatives/workarounds for this?

Here's an example of the way I've setup the `DependencyProperties`:

```
    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(DataBar), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

XML for the UserControl:

```
        x:Name="DataBarUserControl">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="BackgroundRec" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" 
                               Fill="{Binding BarBackground, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Name="ShadowRec" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" Fill="{Binding BarBackground, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0.25" 
               Stroke="{Binding BarBackground, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}">
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Name="DataRec" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" Fill="{Binding BarForeground, ElementName=DataBarUserControl}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

ShadowRec & DataRec are not displayed at all.

**Update 1:**

I think I've found the root cause of the issue. In the backend for the UserControl I modify ShadowRec & DataRec, which are stored as private static variables. When I disable this section of the code, the issue disappears. Not sure if the wrong instance is being grabbed or if there is a more specific way I should be storing the instances.

Comment: hello please post your xaml where the user controls are.

Comment: Posted the XAML with more details regarding the issue.

Comment: ShadowRec and DataRec are behind BackgroundRec. Put the Rectangles in a StackPanel and you will see them.

Comment: @dellywheel: Actually, they are layered correctly: ShadowRec is on BackgroundRec and DataRec is on ShadowRec. As mentioned, this works as expected, but only the first instance of the UserControl. I've even tested disabling all but DataRec, but the issue persists. As mentioned in Update 1, it appears to be an instance issue, not a placement issue.

Comment: ah I see. Using Static variables (instead of Dependency properties) on a usercontrol can lead to all sorts of problems. Probably have to see all your C# code for the usercontrol to be sure whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the instance variables. By removing the instance variables and modifying the ShadowRec & DataRec in the PropertyChangedCallback method, the issue was resolved. For anyone that has a similar issue later on, it should look something like this:

```
    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        GraphBar gb = sender as GraphBar;
        // do something here, such as: gb.DataRec.Width = 15;
    }
```